# Chrome Notifications - Magic Push even when the website is not open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

I have built a chrome extension in the past and I have used chrome notifications API in that extension so I'm familiar with how it works.

I recently found this website which shows this notifications when something happens but the weirdest part is that even when this website is not opened in any tab it pushes these notifications (as long as chrome is open). I want to know how they do it.

I checked my settings->extensions list to see if I installed their extension somehow but there is none. So where are they running this magic javascript from?

Website is called https://www.greentoe.com

Comment: [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web?hl=en) "The reason for this is that when a push message is received, the browser can start up a service worker, **which runs in the background without a page being open**, and dispatch an event so that you can decide how to handle that push message."

Comment: Yes, but when Worker Service is running in the background that pushes these notifications there has to be some Javascript that actually tells the worker service to push them. In usual case it's a chrome extension or a website's javascript. But they are doing it even when the website is not open and no extension is installed.

Comment: Did you follow the link? It points to the google developer site regarding push notifications with all informations you need. Docu, sample repo, demo,...

Comment: @Andreas Would you mind making an actual answer out of that?

Comment: Since no one has mentioned its name, it's called **Push API**.  There are also [services like this](https://pushpad.xyz) that make it straightforward to add it to a website/blog

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web?hl=en) and as stated by @Andreas

> The reason for this is that when a push message is received, the
>   browser can start up a service worker, which runs in the background
>   without a page being open, and dispatch an event so that you can
>   decide how to handle that push message.

The javascript code you are asking for is inside the worker.

If you want to see the workers actually used in your browser just go to `chrome://inspect/#service-workers` in a new tab. You can see the worker code by clicking on the inspect link under the worker name.

Comment: It looks like the URL has changed to `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`, or to check what it is if it changes again, `chrome://chrome-urls/` will list all the internal chrome URLs